# How to evaluate $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2\sin\left(x^2\right)+3+x^2}\,\mathrm dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

How to evaluate $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2\sin\left(x^2\right)+3+x^2}\,\mathrm dx$$
I have no idea how to solve it.Does it have a closed form?

Comment: I would be astound if it has a closed form.

Comment: Did you just make this up, or did the integral actually come from somewhere?

Comment: It's between $\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{5}}$. If it helps :)

Comment: this looks absolutly hopeless but let' s see

Comment: For sure, the value of the integral is not very far from $$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{2\sqrt{x}(3+x+2\min(x,1))}=\frac{\pi}{12}+\frac{\arctan\sqrt{5}}{\sqrt{5}}$$